# Right-angle traces vs curvilinear traces in a PCB

Tags: pcb, heat, conductivity, heat-protection

In a PCB, what is the advantage of using curvilinear copper traces compared to right-angle traces? Can there be a difference in heat dissipation in a right-angle trace that has 270° of free space at the outer vertex and only 90° at the inner vertex, with the same trace adjacent and close by?
The doubt arises from a thermal image seen some time ago of a right-angle PCB trace that showed a higher temperature increase at the inner corner of the trace, but never found again.
The same question formulated theoretically could be: in a cylindrical conductor with a diameter of 1m and a curvature of 2m radius, does more current pass along the shortest path of the conductor or evenly along the surface of the conductor (skin effect)?

Comment: Most of the reason I'm aware of for avoiding sharp angles is for RF.  At DC, I don't see an issue for heating assuming track length is the same.